# How to use Vim buffer window as Unix Shell

Tags: vim, gvim

Is it possible use a split a window in (g)vim as unix shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not nativelly. But [there's a plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2771) for that.